# Supabase CLI (local development) problems with RLS and enabling realtime

Tags: supabase

I've used the Supabase CLI for some time now with some minor hiccups but overall ok.

When applying another change yesterday though, I ran into a couple of serious issues:

1. In the studio no RLS policies are visible (they are present and applied, just not visible in the local Supabase studio)
2. I fail to enable realtime on tables via Supabase studio

Does anyone have suggestions on why this might be? Solutions or workarounds?

Context:

- Supabase CLI is installed via brew and at version 1.113.2.
- I have tried resetting the database and restarting the local environment.
- I tried the beta version

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a problem with the latest version of the Supabase CLI and downgrading to 1.110.3 solves the issues. see these GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/supabase/cli/issues/1683
- https://github.com/supabase/cli/issues/1684

To easiest way to downgrade is to install the specific version via the package manager:

```
pnpm add supabase@1.110.3 --save-dev -w
```

and then restart the CLI with

```
npx supabase stop; npx supabase start
```